# EF Core 2.1 [change tracking] - saving all related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1, change-tracking

Maybe the title is misunderstood but I'm gonna try to explain my situation here.

So, considering my entity `Person` that has a virtual property `Country`, as follows:

```
public class Person {
    public long Id { get; set;}
    public short IdCountry { get; set;}
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and the mapping as follows:

```
...
builder.HasOne(c => c.Country)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.IdCountry);
```

and my repository is generic.

What happens here is, when I try to save some change in `Person`, the `Country` entity state came to me as `Added` which does not make sense.

I'm exposing here a similar example that what is happening to me. Actually, I have like five others virtual properties in my class `Person` and some of them are in this state (`Added`).

Has anyone ever dealt with it before?
Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: Answering @alans reply: I'm doing something similar as follow:

```
foreach (var entrie in entry.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    try
    {
        key = entrie.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(entrie.Entity, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        key = null;
    }
    if (key != null && entrie.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        entrie.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
    else if (Convert.ChangeType(key, typeof(long)) as long? == 0)
    {
        entrie.State = EntityState.Added;
    }
}
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

@TanvirArjel this method above is where the state come as `Added`

Comment: Are you running TrackGraph on Update?

Comment: @thatsallfolks Where is code in where Country entity state came as Added? Please add those code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `AsNoTracking()` extension method for performance questions in EF6 but I realized that in EFCore **this particular method** is a little bit different (I was migrating the code). So, I only removed the method

Answer (score -1):

Are you newing up the Country object somewhere? If the property's key has a default value it will me marked as added. That's my guess.